# How to add plugin for Excel Online?

Tags: c#, excel, plugins, web-applications

I would like to use Excel functionality from a browser. I currently have an excel based Microsoft office application. It adds an icon to the ribbon and does C# based custom application logic to communicate to a database server.

Since it requires application releases for any changes in the schema I am curious if I can convert this into an web application and still benefit from Excel's built in functionality.

I am expecting this to be possible since Microsoft Excel Online is run inside a browser. My question is, is it possible to add plugin to such online excel document? If yes, any example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can, and depending on approach you can do so with nothing more than a VSTO project template. This is little more than a ClickOnce application. This can launch a browser within a window to perform the logic.

You may use the Office Interop assemblies to decouple your application from Office apps, yet still communicate easily. Make sure you set Embed Interop Assemblies to true once added as a reference.

For those using Office in the browser, it seems as though Microsoft is shifting into CSOM/JSON/REST, meaning this solution is coded entirely differently than COM. This should help you get started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn268594.aspx.